# Why char pointer could add value after it signed?

Tags: c, pointers

The output is A A Z. I am having trouble to understand the last output 'Z'.

```
int main(){
   char a,b,c,*p;

    a = 'A';
    p = &a;
    b = *p;
    p = &c;
    *p = 'Z';

   printf("%c %c %c\n",a,b,c);
   return(0);
}
```

Why `*p = 'Z';` could sign the letter 'Z' to c after `p = &c`?
Thank you

Comment: Don't use an image to show your code, copy paste it here using code block. See [ask]

Comment: @MickaelB. Where on that page is the question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

`*p` equals `c`

## Explanation

Hi, first take a look at how to format a question on stack overflow. You should write your code directly in the question.

So your question is about the understanding of these lines:

```
    char c,*p;
    p = &c
    *p = 'Z'
    printf("%c", c) // 'Z'
```

First you're declaring two different type of variable:

- `char c;` a char can store in memory 1 byte
- `char *p;` a **pointer** of char. A pointer hold a memory address. In this case the memory address of a char

Then by doing `p = &c` you're storing the memory address of `c` in the pointer `p`.

> `&c` means the memory address of c.
>
> `*p` means the value of the memory address stored in p

Finally by doing `*p = 'Z'` you're setting the value at the memory address stored in p to 'Z'. And because p store the memory address of c, c is set to 'Z'.

If you still not confident about this, make some research about pointers.

Comment: Do I still have to format my code? I posted a picture and removed at the beginning. I used ctrl+k to included my code. Is that correct?

Comment: Your question reformating is nice. it's exactly how you format a stackoverflow question. Only the title is not good.

Comment: lol thanks. I will change it